# Is it possible to include the results of a if/else statement in a message box but multiple values instead of one

Tags: c#

I have a MessageBox that prompts the user if he/she wants to disable everything that they have enabled at once,

```
DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("You currently Have : " + Environment.NewLine 
    + "// Empty Space" + Environment.NewLine 
    + "//Option 1" + Environment.NewLine 
    + "//Option 2" + Environment.NewLine 
    + "//Option 3" + Environment.NewLine 
    + "//Empty Space" + Environment.NewLine
    + "Active For Client 1 Would You Like To Disable All Mods For This Player ?",
        "Disable all Client 1's Options",
        MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);

        if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
        {

        }
        else if (result == DialogResult.No)
        {

        }
```

so when an input has been enabled earlier on in the code it updates the string value in Settings.settings (Visual Studio 2015 Windows Forms Application) with the value enabled. 
To summarise what I was trying to achieve is to automatically detect if that string value equals 'enabled' and if it does it returns the string name inside the message box

Example :
[Example of MessageBox How I Need It Displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4urq0.png)

Please Help

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting everything inside the DialogResult constructor,
Since you do have Settings where you store these settings, either go through them in another method 
or query them in key-value fashion flags indicating disabled, i.e.,

```
String dialogRes = String.Empty;
if(String.isNullorEmpty(SettingObj["mySetting"].toString()) 
{
  dialogRes = $@"{dialogRes} 
              {SettingObj["mySetting"].toString()}"; //format it your way with "@" spacing
}
```

Once you have this dialogRes, display it, if the user says yes, turn all your setting strings null or empty.

Comment: Cheers, i fugured it out i ended up inputting a timer to loop every so 5 seconds to update the value in the settings page to a empty string then just called it from there